# connect via putty to google instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, putty, ssh-keys

it is long story but to cut short
I need to reset plesk admin password, which you cant reset from forget password
to do that,
I loged to SSH 
then I became root - sudo su command
then I applied 
sudo passwd to create root password
then to reveal plesk password
/usr/local/psa/bin/admin --show-password  - nothing happened
plesk bin admin --set-admin-password -passwd new_password  --nothing happen

I thought connecting via putty to instance as root might help
to do that
I have to create public key which I did via putty key generator.

I applied ssh-keygen command in SSH
I gave a passphrase
I got result as
Your identification has been saved in root-ssh-key.

here comes the question
open putty type ip adress when login as comes
I type root
then this error comesup
Disconnected: no supported authentication methods available ( blablabla )
http://prntscr.com/gzkgbf

so how can I connect via putty as root to instance ???

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Root and admin passwords are not related: root password is used to access your server over SSH, while admin password is used to access Plesk interface in a browser.

To reset the password for admin user in Plesk web interface, log in as root to the server over SSH and execute this command:
plesk bin admin --set-password -passwd *****

replace **** with desired password for Plesk interface.

This way you will be able to login to Plesk at https://yourIPorHostname:8443 under admin user and the password that you have just set.